# Deformation of finite coverings between smooth projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Assume that we have a finite covering $$f \colon X \longrightarrow Y,$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are smooth, complex projective varieties of dimension $n$. Therefore we obtain a splitting $$f_* \mathscr{O}_X = \mathscr{O}_Y \oplus   \mathscr{E},$$ where $\mathscr{E}$ is a vector bundle on $Y$ of rank $n-1$. Moreover, we have a short exact sequence $$0 \longrightarrow T_X \stackrel{df}{\longrightarrow} f^*T_Y \longrightarrow N_f \longrightarrow 0,$$
where $N_f$ is a coherent sheaf supported on the ramification locus of $f$ and called the *normal sheaf* of $f$.

Passing to cohomology, we obtain a linear map $$\psi \colon H^1(X, T_X) \longrightarrow H^1(X, \, f^*T_Y).$$ By standard deformation theory, this is a map between the space of first order deformations of $X$ to the obstruction space to deforming the map $f$ (keeping both $X$ and $Y$ fixed). I admit that the geometrical meaning of $\psi$ is still not clear to me: in fact, given a first order deformation of $X$, I do not see any natural way to associate to it an obstruction to deforming $f$.

Furthermore, using projection formula, the map $\psi$ becomes a map $$\eta \colon H^1(X, \, T_X) \longrightarrow H^1(Y, \, T_Y) \oplus H^1(Y, \, T_Y \otimes \mathscr{E}).$$

> **Question.** Is there any natural interpretation of the maps $\psi$ and $\eta$ in terms of deformations of $X$, $Y$ and deformations of the map $f$?
>
> For instance, what are the first order deformations of $X$ mapping into $H^1(Y, \, T_Y)$ via $\eta$?

Any reference to the existing literature will be particularly appreciated.

Comment: A good reference is Section 6 of K. Behrend, B. Fantechi, "The Intrinsic Normal Cone", Invent. Math. 128 (1997), 45-88.  The adjoint of $df$ gives a perfect complex concentrated in amplitude $[-1,0]$ that is quasi-isomorphic to the cotangent complex $L_f$ of $f$.  The hyperext group $RHom^1_{\mathcal{O}_X}(L_f,\mathcal{O}_X[0])$ is the space of first-order deformations of the pair $(X,f:X\to Y)$ with $Y$ held fixed.  In your setting, this is the same as $H^0(X,N_f)$.  Thus the image of an element under $\psi$ equals $0$ if and only if there is a corresponding first-order deformation of $f$.

Comment: I guess *the* reference is Prop. III.2.1.2.3, p. 186, Luc Illusie, "Complexe cotangent et deformations, I", Lect. Notes in Math. 239, Springer-Verlag, Berlin - New York, 1971.

Comment: @JasonStarr: This is interesting, thank you for the references. Do you know anything about $\eta$? For instance, can one characterize the first order deformations of $X$ mapping onto the first summand $H^1(Y, \, T_Y)$?

Comment: I've made an edit of the question about this specific point.

Comment: It should be in Illusie -- I will check.  I believe the point is that, for a given flat family of Y's over a base, the obstruction to deforming $(X,f:X\to Y)$ to match that $Y$ lives in the same group.  So probably that has something to do with the map from $H^1(Y,T_Y)$ to the obstruction group.

Comment: I am a little rusty, but it seems that Prop. 2.1.4.5 on p. 189 says, for a given deformation of $Y$ over an (Artinian?) base $Z$ whose associated first order deformation is $e(Y)$ in $H^1(Y,T_Y)$, for a given closed subscheme $\overline{Z}\hookrightarrow Z$ whose ideal sheaf is a square-zero ideal $I$, for a given extension of $(X,f:X\to Y)$ over $\overline{Z}$, the element in $H^1(X,N_f)\otimes I = RHom^2_{\mathcal{O}_X}(L_f,\mathcal{O}_X[0])\otimes I$ measuring existence of a lift is the image of the pullback of $e(Y)$ in $H^1(X,f^*T_Y)\otimes I$ . . .

Comment: . . .  Thus, when $Z$ is $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[\epsilon]/\langle \epsilon^2 \rangle)$, for a given first-deformation $e(Y)\in H^1(Y,T_Y)$, for a first-order deformation $e(X)$ in $H^1(X,T_X)$, there exists a corresponding first-order deformation of $f$ with respect to $e(Y)$ and $e(X)$ if and only if the image of $e(X)$ in $H^1(X,f^*T_Y)$ equals the pullback of $e(Y)$.